# Multiple Flextables in RMarkdown chunk (with echo = F) do not render

Tags: flextable

I am using R 3.5.1 on OS Windows 7 x64. 
My package versions are:
flextable: 0.5.1
officer: 0.3.2
tidyverse: 1.2.1
tidyr: 0.8.2

I am trying to create and then print multiple flextables in a single chunk to Word. I also do not want the actual R code in the Word Doc, so I've set echo = FALSE. However, I've run into something strange.

If I use the following code (echo = T):

````
```{r, echo = F, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
library(officer)
```

```{r, echo = T}
iris_data <- head(iris, n = 10)
iris_data_ft <- iris_data %>% flextable() %>%
    hline(part = 'header', border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 3)) %>%
    align(align ='center', part = 'all') %>%
    align(j = 1, align ='left', part = 'all') %>%
    add_header_lines('this is a test')
iris_data_ft

iris_data2 <- tail(iris, n = 10)
iris_data2_ft <- iris_data2 %>% flextable() %>%
    hline(part = 'header', border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 3)) %>%
    align(align ='center', part = 'all') %>%
    align(j = 1, align ='left', part = 'all') %>%
    add_header_lines('this is a test')
iris_data2_ft
```
````

I get the following output of proper flextables in Word:
[image]

If I use the exact same code, but with echo = F:

````
```{r, echo = F}
iris_data <- head(iris, n = 10)
iris_data_ft <- iris_data %>% flextable() %>%
    hline(part = 'header', border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 3)) %>%
    align(align ='center', part = 'all') %>%
    align(j = 1, align ='left', part = 'all') %>%
    add_header_lines('this is a test')
iris_data_ft

iris_data2 <- tail(iris, n = 10)
iris_data2_ft <- iris_data2 %>% flextable() %>%
    hline(part = 'header', border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 3)) %>%
    align(align ='center', part = 'all') %>%
    align(j = 1, align ='left', part = 'all') %>%
    add_header_lines('this is a test')
iris_data2_ft
```
````

I get the following in Word (this goes on for 58 pages):
[image: flextablesEchoF]

Finally, if I split the one chunk for the two flextables into two separate chunks and set echo = F:

````
```{r, echo = F}
iris_data <- head(iris, n = 10)
iris_data_ft <- iris_data %>% flextable() %>%
    hline(part = 'header', border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 3)) %>%
    align(align ='center', part = 'all') %>%
    align(j = 1, align ='left', part = 'all') %>%
    add_header_lines('this is a test')
iris_data_ft
```

```{r, echo = F}
iris_data2 <- tail(iris, n = 10)
iris_data2_ft <- iris_data2 %>% flextable() %>%
    hline(part = 'header', border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 3)) %>%
    align(align ='center', part = 'all') %>%
    align(j = 1, align ='left', part = 'all') %>%
    add_header_lines('this is a test')
iris_data2_ft
```
````

The tables render just fine:
[image: flextablesEchoFtwoChunks]

While I don't mind separating the flextables into different chunks, I am wondering why this is happening. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)
```

```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(htmltools)
ft <- flextable(head(iris))
for(i in 1:3){
  cat("```{=openxml}\n")
  cat(format(ft, type = "wml"), "\n")
  cat("```\n")
}
```
````

Comment: This does not work either, no table is output. Produces a word document with "Untitled" as the only content

Comment: This answer is old now. See `?flextable::flextable_to_rmd` for printing in loop

Answer (score -1):

I guess this issue is solved with newer versions of flextable already. If I put the code following two chunks into a .Rmd document and knit to word it compiles without problems and shows tables, even if put into one chunk with `echo = F`. Just wanted to add: In some cases it might be helpful to add `results='asis'` - the 'as is'-option (raw Markdown parsing) - to your chunk header to prevent errors when parsing tables, check: [bookdown.org/results-as-is](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/results-asis.html).

````
```{r, echo = F, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
library(officer) 
```

```{r, echo = F}
iris_data <- head(iris, n = 10)
iris_data_ft <- iris_data %>% flextable() %>%
    hline(part = 'header', border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 3)) %>%
    align(align ='center', part = 'all') %>%
    align(j = 1, align ='left', part = 'all') %>%
    add_header_lines('this is a test')
iris_data_ft

iris_data2 <- tail(iris, n = 10)
iris_data2_ft <- iris_data2 %>% flextable() %>%
    hline(part = 'header', border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 3)) %>%
    align(align ='center', part = 'all') %>%
    align(j = 1, align ='left', part = 'all') %>%
    add_header_lines('this is a test')
iris_data2_ft
```
````

Comment: Try putting your answer into a loop and you will see that it does not work

Comment: I did and it does work. Share your error message pls.